# Collection view controller's viewDidLayoutSubviews is being called repeatedly in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios7

I have a collection view controller with a vertical flow layout, which has some custom layout attributes to warp it into a semicircle, but is otherwise fairly normal.  Under iOS 6, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called precisely twice, once when the view is initialised, and again after it has got its data.  But under iOS 7, it is then getting called repeatedly whenever the collection view scrolls, whether with finger down or under its own momentum.  It looks like it could be once per didscroll.  Does anybody know the reason why this might be happening in 7?

Comment: Because iOS 7 is awesome!  It is guaranteeing employment for many of us programmers because it has so many unexpected and inexplicable features.

Comment: That's true, although I'd rather work down a mine that isn't going to collapse.

Comment: Amen.  I've had a rough week dealing with changes for some apps that I didn't write.

Answer (score 8):

Ok so according to this post by nickman55 on the Apple forums, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called in iOS 7 whenever a collection view cell is reused.  https://devforums.apple.com/message/874718#874718